# Conditions for splitting of short exact sequence?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, homological-algebra, elliptic-curves

Assume $K$ is a number field and $E$ is an elliptic curve defined over $K$.

Are there conditions under which the short exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow E (K)/mE (K)\rightarrow H^1_{Sel}(K,E_m)\rightarrow Sha(E|K)_m\rightarrow 0$$
splits?

References?

Comment: It is just a short exact sequence of $m$-torsion abelian groups. It quite easy to give examples and conditions for both cases. I don't think you can hope for anything else.

Comment: Doesn't it split if $E$ has no $m$-torsion? Then you can write all the groups as quotients of their $m$-adic versions and use classification of modules over a PID.